# How to color actually labels and arrows using xy/xymatrix package

Tags: color, xy-pic, xymatrix

I'm reading actually the `xyrefer.pdf` guide to give a color to the arrow and to the label. Starting from this MWE, there is not any color for the arrow (for example).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[color,cmtip,all]{xy}
%\xyoption{color}
%\UseCrayolaColors
\begin{document}
\xymatrix
{
A \ar@[red][r]^a&  B\\
}
\end{document}
```

How can I obtain a colour to the vector and to the label?

Comment: Did you already try with `\usepackage{xcolor}` in the preamble?

Comment: @leandriis Yes, of course. I have an error: `Xy-pic error: No 'xcolor' option. [\ProcessOptions\relax]`.

Comment: Interesting. For me, the following MWEgives the following output: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[color,cmtip,all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix
{
A \ar@[red][r]^{\color{blue}a}&  B\\
}
\end{document}`Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRenG.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the option `dvips`, if you using `LaTeX` -> `dvips` -> `PS2PDF` and if you didn't given any option, then it will assume `PDFLaTeX` is the default driver:

**MWE**

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvips,color,matrix,arrow]{xy} 
\begin{document} 

\xymatrix { A
\ar@[red][r]^{\color{blue}a}& B\\
} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much...for your answer...."Grazie assai".

Comment: @Sebastiano It's my pleasure to give suggestion like you! (I know you are one of a `LaTeX` great)...and thank you so much for your complimentary comment...

Comment: Thank you very much again: "(I know you are one of a LaTeX great)"--> It is not true.